# CatchError function of response interceptor execute multiple times - Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

I created a interceptor for my angular project to intercept all the requests and responses, but the function that validates errors in the responses is executed 7 times.

I realized that when I use the `throwError` of `rjxs` it performs the function many times, if I use the `of` `rxjs` it executes only one, but fails to execute functions that validate errors in subscribes.

```
constructor(private injector: Injector, public errorHandler: ApplicationErrorHandler) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const sessaoService = this.injector.get(SessaoService);
    if (sessaoService.isLoogedIn()) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const tokenSplit = token.split(' ');
        request = request.clone(
            { setHeaders: { 'Authorization': `${tokenSplit[1]}` } }
        );
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log('Execute function');
            let data = {};
            data = {
                error: err,
                status: err.status,
                method: request.method
            };

            this.errorHandler.handleError(data);
            return throwError(err);
        })
    );
}
```

I expect that catchError function execute only one time, but it is running 7 times for each request.

My Angular version is: 6.1.3;
My Rxjs version is: 6.4.0;

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: `catchError` is used to remplace an error stream with a valid stream. `throwError` is used to transform a valid stream into an error stream. So basically, you're going forward, then backwards, then forward ... Could you explain what are you trying to do ?

Comment: And please, provide a [mcve] and your full code. Seems like you used the `retry` operator.

Comment: I'm trying to validate response errors, when an error comes in the response I pass it to the "errorHandler" which has some validations to display the error. 
I'm not trying to give a retry.

Comment: What does "validate response errors" mean ? Because as far as I can see, you're just calling a function that has **no influence** on the stream itself. Then you're returning an error stream with `throwError`, which can then trigger the `retry` operators in your services. But then again, your full code and a [mcve] would help greatly. Unless you post them, I highly doubt you will get an answer.

Comment: Add code, I'll be adding and arranging the rest for you. https://github.com/jsilveira2/catchError-Demonstrantion

Comment: Dude, I'm not doing your work for you ! use https://stackblitz.com and make a very simple reproduction of your issue, it will be enough to see your issue.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I use stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4mfkw

Comment: Well if you could make it work too ...

Comment: Is that basically to run it needs to make a request to an api. But what I'm trying to do is simple: Request starting from login.ponent.ts> Arrives at session.service.ts> Request is intercepted by auth.interceptor.ts> pipe at next.handle has a catchError that contains a function, this function is being executed 7 times when there is any response error. Again, sorry for my bad english I really do not know how to express myself correctly sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I have a shared module in my application and inside it I had added HTTP_INTERCEPTORS as provider using my class with theintercept function.